# Handle Active selection of a button in a better way

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

ts

```
isDayClicked: { [key: number]: boolean } = {};


  constructor() { }

  setSelectedDay(day: string, index: number): void {

    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        this.isDayClicked[0] = true;
        this.isDayClicked[1] = false;
        this.isDayClicked[2] = false;
        break;
      case 1:
        this.isDayClicked[0] = false;
        this.isDayClicked[1] = true;
        this.isDayClicked[2] = false;
        break;
      case 2:
        this.isDayClicked[0] = false;
        this.isDayClicked[1] = false;
        this.isDayClicked[2] = true;
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
```

html

```
<ion-col size="4" *ngFor="let d of validDays;let i = index;">
      <ion-button expand="block" fill="outline" 
        [ngClass]="{'active':isDayClicked[i]}" (click)="setSelectedDay(d,i)">
        {{d}}
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
```

css

```
.active {
    background-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
}
```

UI

[image]

I have buttons as shown above. I need to show an active button. So I have used the above trick. But it seems hardcoded thing. i.e. `this.isDayClicked[0] = true;this.isDayClicked[1] = false;this.isDayClicked[2] = false;` Do I have a better way to handle this kind of use case?

**Note:** The above approach is working perfectly fine. But I would like to do it in a better way.

Comment: This question belongs to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: create a variable `selectedIndex`, by default value can be null. on click on button you can  set `selectedIndex == current index of button`.

then in `[ngClass]="{'active': selectedIndex === i}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this.

create a new variable in your ts file

```
public selectedIndex = null;
```

then in your setSelectedDay function change this variable.

```
setSelectedDay(day: string, index: number): void {
  this.selectedIndex = index
}
```

then in your html do like this.

```
<ion-col size="4" *ngFor="let d of validDays;let i = index;">
  <ion-button expand="block" fill="outline" 
    [ngClass]="{'active':selectedIndex === i}" (click)="setSelectedDay(d,i)">
    {{d}}
  </ion-button>
</ion-col>
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.